# How to run postgresql function (seeing error while running)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created Postgresql function like this. And tried different ways to run it as mentioned in this question. None of the works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_update_count(
  updateType text,
  userid     text
)
  RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    _qry char(1024);
    l_rows integer;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Running ++';
    IF updateType = '+' THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Running ++';
        UPDATE user_account SET tptcount = tptcount + 1 WHERE useridcode = '@userid';
    ELSIF updateTYpe = '-' THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Running --';
        UPDATE user_account SET tptcount = tptcount - 1 WHERE useridcode = '@userid';
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Not running any';
    END IF;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS l_rows = ROW_COUNT; 
    RETURN l_rows;  
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Tried to execute function like this:

**Runs successfully:**

```
UPDATE user_account SET tptcount = tptcount + 1 WHERE useridcode = 'chris_32';
```

=====

Seeing error: `ERROR:  prepared statement "func_update_count" does not exist` for below query.

```
EXECUTE func_update_count("+", "chris_32"); -- Does not work
```

=====

Seeing error: `ERROR:  column "+" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT func_update_count("+", "chris_32"); -- Does not work` for below query

```
SELECT func_update_count("+", "chris_32"); -- Does not work
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seeing error: ERROR:  prepared statement "func_update_count" does not exist for below query.

`EXECUTE` is used for executing prepared statements, not running postgresql functions. See [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) in the manual.

You would execute a function by calling it from a query (as per your second attempt).

> Seeing error: ERROR:  column "+" does not exist

Double quotes `"` are used to quote identifiers if they have spaces in them (eg. `"my column"`), or to preserve case (eg. `"MyColumn"`).

See [Syntax for Identifiers and Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Single quotes (`'`) can be used for string literals, as well as other styles - see [Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, the values within double quotes are interpreted as references to columns rather than string literals. Thus:

```
SELECT func_update_count("+", "chris_32"); 
 --pulls values from the column named + and column named chris_32
```

Should probably be:

```
SELECT func_update_count('+', 'chris_32');
```